# ImagePicker: Error returned from daemon: Error Domain=com.apple.accounts Code=7 "(null)"

Tags: ios, swift, imagepicker

I'm new to this but, I'm getting this error at the Image Picker and I'm stuck:

```
Error returned from daemon: Error Domain=com.apple.accounts Code=7 "(null)"
```

PHPhotoLibrary.requestAuthorization gives me "authorized", so it seems no permission problem and I have the asset .Album being returned, but I can't load the images...

Comment: Same issue here. Any updates on this? :(